# Connecting TV and computer with two routers

Tags: networking, router, tv

My network is like this:

A Thomson TG508v2 modem/router connects to the internet and connected to it we have:

- Computer 1
- Computer 2
- An EA6500 router

In the EA6500 router we have:

- A TV
- A PS3

and we also use it as the main wifi router for the whole house since it is better positioned and has a better range than the TG508v2

The thing is, Computer 1 has a DLNA server and I wish to use it from my TV which as you can notice is connected in another router.

The first answer will probably be: use your EA6500 in bridge mode, but:

1. I lose a lot of the EA6500 features doing that.
2. For some strange reason, the internet in the mobile devices (wifi) starts to have some bugs when I do that, The youtube app takes a lot to load videos (like 2 minutes just to start buffering) and my sister always has some strange stuff happening in her iphone/ipad. While using the EA6500 as a router in a different subnet I don't have those problems.

I also wish that everything could work almost as if there was only one subnet (everything could ping everything) but without losing the EA6500 features (plugins HDs to it, better network controls than over the TG580v2, etc....).

The TG580v2 has crappy/no way to configure routes, and the EA6500 has nat enabled.

Connecting the computers to the EA6500 will be almost impossible

Any suggestions?

Comment: Using the EA6500 as just an access point makes the most sense. Why don't you want to do that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Connect to Computers in different router network](http://superuser.com/questions/305841/connect-to-computers-in-different-router-network)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Having two different subnets will cause problems as you have found out.

A better solution that would address all the issues would be to convert your EA6500 from a wireless router, to a wireless access point.

Give the EA6500 a static IP address
Turn of dhcp services on the EA6500
Plug the network cable into the LAN port (not the WAN port)

Doing these steps will give you one subnet, will still let you use the EA6500 for wireless because it is a better location, and you don't need to mess with bridging, or port forwarding; thus satisfying all of your requirements.

Comment: I wish I could have the EA6500 doing all the DHCP/routing istead of my crappy modem, I think that impossible/really hard, but that solution appears to be good enough. Thanks man!